# how to remove duplicate values in hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap

i have a hashmap and i am entering values in the hashmap using the same keys.I want to inser the value in the database only if that value is not present in the databse.

here's my code

```
 s11=json_data.getString("phno");
        Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {                                              
    String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
    String value=(String)map.get(key);
         if(s11.compareTo(value)==0)
         {//String name2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(s11 ));
         queryValues.put("c",value);
         //Cursor cursr = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",           new String[] { s11 }, null);
         // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"get particular name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         db.insertcontact(queryValues);
         // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         }
```

Comment: i'd suggest overriding the equals method to your class, and before adding the value to the hashmap use the method contains(obj) before

Comment: i would suggest to use hashset for your requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579863/advantages-of-using-a-hashset-over-hashmap http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java

Answer (score 4):

can you use this way?

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm=new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 
hm.put("AK",1); 
hm.put("BK",2); 
hm.put("CK",3); 
hm.put("DK",4); 
hm.put("EK",5); 
hm.put("FK",6); 
hm.put("GK",7); 
hm.put("HK",6); 
hm.put("IK",7); 


System.out.println("values are "+hm.values()); 

// Removing the duplicate VALUES from Map 
System.out.println("\n After removing duplicate values "); 

for(Object key1:hm.keySet()){ 

for(Object key2:hm.keySet()){ 
if(!key1.toString().equals(key2.toString())){ 
int x=hm.get(key1); 
int y=hm.get(key2); 
if(x==y){ 
    hm.remove(key2); 
} 
} 

}
}
```